# Do expanded usercard views count towards profile views?

Tags: support, views, user-card

Do people really check out my profile page that often on SO or do they just hover their cursors above my usercard and that counts as a profile view?

UPD: okay, now that this is a support question, maybe all those are just from my own views? I sometimes start browsing SO from my own profile page there. I wonder if that counts as a profile view too. Because I'm fairly sure my own question view count rises when I view it after some time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure user card isn't counted as profile view. 500 views in year and half are not that much. People might find one of your posts interesting so browsing your profile to see more posts you have. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I'm trying to figure out if there's a dependency on total question score and profile view count on SE sites. The number differs from site to site. I mean there have to be people who might want to find out my background in some area (related to the question) and on some sites it doesn't even matter (like languages).

Comment: Think we can't really know that... hope to get official answer from a dev here about user card, but apart of that even the dev team can't answer about the dependency between reputation and views except some data that you can find yourself in http://data.stackexchange.com/ :)